# How to setup SDK in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sdk, ide, ubuntu-16.04

I am not finding any way to setup the SDK in IntelliJ IDEA.
Not finding any path to setup the SDK in ubuntu 16.04 LTS for IntelliJ IDEA.

[image]

I am working in this IDE for working on mongodb. But can't proceed because of this problem.

Comment: I add SDKs in global settings and choose the one I want in project settings.  Both are on the top menu bar.

Comment: Refer [to help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/working-with-sdks.html?search=jsdk#sdk_when_creating_project). If you don't have JDK installed, [get one here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the path where java is installed on ubuntu, you can run the following command from terminal:

```
$ whereis java
```

You may get something like this:

```
java: /usr/bin/java /etc/java /usr/share/java /usr/lib/jvm
```

Which means that the java resides at one of the above paths as for example `/usr/bin/java`

So, that directory should designate in IntelliJ. You can configure in the `Project Structure`, press `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S`, choose `Platform Settings -> SDKs`, click on green button `(+)`, select the home directory for JDK.

Comment: I am not able to find the same directory of java in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, in windows your answer is helpful but not finding the same dir in Ubuntu.

Comment: sorry by the mistake, I improved the answer, I hope it useful

Comment: Even though it is accepted, it is wrong.   Look under `/usr/lib/jvm`.

Comment: dont understand why its accepted ...this not a correct answer.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen thank you for your input, when I searched the java path with the previous command I found those paths, however I updated the answer with your suggestion

Comment: I get those paths but I cannot add them as SDK folder to IntelliJ setting.

Comment: @Ben maybe you only have JRE and not JDK, you can try to manually download the JDK and setting it up as DaniloTeodoro explains in his post

Answer (score 4):

If you don't happen to have a **JDK** installed you can download the latest version [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

You can unpack it to your home directory so that you don't need extra permissions:

```
~/Downloads$  tar zxvf jdk-<version>-linux-x64.tar.gz -C ~/java/jdk/
```

And finally reference your new JDK on IntelliJ:
[image: Project Structure SDK setup]

Answer (score 0):

Alt+ Ctrl + Shift + S  - Project