# OpenJDK-9 JDK not present on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java, java-9, ubuntu-17.10

I'm trying to install java 9 jre and jdk on ubuntu. But i cannot find it. I installed all the packages:

`ii openjdk-9-jdk:amd64 9~b181-4 amd64 OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)
ii openjdk-9-jdk-headless:amd64 9~b181-4 amd64 OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) (headless)
ii openjdk-9-jre:amd64 9~b181-4 amd64 OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
ii openjdk-9-jre-headless:amd64 9~b181-4 amd64 OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)`

Java -version returns:

`openjdk version "9-Ubuntu"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-Ubuntu+0-9b181-4)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-Ubuntu+0-9b181-4, mixed mode)`

javac -version:

`javac 9-Ubuntu`

But when I try to create JDK in new Intellij:
[image]

Then i get error:

[image]

I checked the content of /usr/lib/jvm/ and:

For java-8-openjdk-amd64:

`drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 gru 17 16:16 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 gru 18 18:11 ../
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   22 paź 24 00:43 ASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION -> jre/ASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 gru 17 16:16 bin/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   41 paź 24 00:43 docs -> ../../../share/doc/openjdk-8-jre-headless/
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 gru 17 16:16 include/
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 gru 17 16:16 jre/
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 gru 17 16:16 lib/
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 gru 17 16:16 man/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 paź 24 00:43 src.zip -> ../openjdk-8/src.zip
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   22 paź 24 00:43 THIRD_PARTY_README -> jre/THIRD_PARTY_README`

For java-9-openjdk-amd64:

`drwxr-xr-x  9 root root 4096 gru 18 18:11 ./
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 gru 18 18:11 ../
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 gru 18 18:11 bin/
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 gru 18 18:11 conf/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   41 sie 24 19:15 docs -> ../../../share/doc/openjdk-9-jre-headless/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 gru 18 18:11 include/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 gru 18 18:11 jmods/
drwxr-xr-x 77 root root 4096 gru 18 18:11 legal/
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 gru 18 18:11 lib/
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 gru 18 18:11 man/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   20 sie 24 19:15 src.zip -> ../openjdk-9/src.zip`

My question is what went wrong? To install java-9 i used:

> sudo apt install openjdk-9-jre openjdk-9-jdk

Comment: The Java 9 JDK structure is very different from Java 8. You need to make sure you hava a new enough version of IntelliJ that understands the structure.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.1 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-173.3942.27, built on December 11, 2017

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Properly set up Java 9 as SDK in Intellij IDEA on Linux due to new folder structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47296429/properly-set-up-java-9-as-sdk-in-intellij-idea-on-linux-due-to-new-folder-struct)

Answer (score 0):

I found an issue on idea tracker
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-178743
It's fixed. Also users suggested x86_64- version. Try with it.[(source)](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/09/java-9-and-intellij-idea/)