# OpenJDK 11 IntelliJ IDEA (Ubuntu) “Can't resolve Symbol String”

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea

After updating to 2019.1.3, IntelliJ  (Community Edition) stopped recognizing any of the built-in java classes on my development machine. 
I get the following error:

> Can't resolve Symbol String

[image: Can't resolve Symbol String]

I first thought the JDK was not configured properly, but it doesn't look like so:

[image]

I can see all the java base classes, including java.lang.String, under the "External dependencies" panel in IntelliJ :

[image]

I tried to reinstall the JDK, without any success:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove openjdk-11-jdk
sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk
```

I also invalidated caches and restarted IntelliJ, also unsuccessfully.

Compilation from the command line works fine.

Comment: Which IntelliJ version you are using?

Comment: I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-191.7479.19, built on May 28, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b58 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.15.0-51-generic

I will add this information to the question.

Comment: It seems this pose here has the same issue https://askubuntu.com/questions/1101033/in-intellij-from-snap-i-cant-select-openjdk-11-from-apt-get

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like no one found a solution to the question you link. One answer is about someone who did not use the right path to the jdk, another is the OP saying he switched to oracle's JDK.

Comment: Not sure if related, would be odd if 11 as the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47296429/properly-set-up-java-9-as-sdk-in-intellij-idea-on-linux-due-to-new-folder-struct/47850159#47850159

Comment: Have you tried ti remove SDK in IDEA and re-add it?

Comment: Yes, I tried to remove the SDK and re-add it. I also tried OpenJDK 8 and Oracle's JDK 12. Always the same result. I am going to try and delete IntelliJ and reinstall it.

Comment: Don't forget to clean directories used to store setting/configs: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 19.10 and could solved as follows:

Intellij IDEA

File -> Project Structure -> SDK ->

JDK home path: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java

Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

I updated my plugins within IntelliJ which caused IntelliJ to reindex again.

Apparently, that did the trick and it is working fine now for me.

Comment: Note that there is also an "invalidate caches and restart" action in the File menu, that sometimes achieves wonders.